# Run script from package.json from different directory

Tags: node.js, bash, package.json

I'm writing a batch script which exports a few variables and then tries to execute `npm run`.
Here's the example script:

```
#!/bin/bash -e
# External Services
export EXTERNAL_ENVIRONMENT="test"
export ENVIRONMENT="sandbox"

npm run --prefix payment-methods-tests
```

But the call to `npm run` does not work.
The script is located in:
`project/scripts/run.sh` while `package.json` is located under `project`

Is it possible to call npm run withou the bash script being in the same directory as `package.json` ?